# xml xpath search excludes parent node, but recursive search doesn't

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

The documentation for `scala-xml-1.0.6_12.4` xpath `\` says:

> ```
> def \(that: String): NodeSeq
> ```
>
> Projection function, which returns elements of this sequence based on the string that.

But if you look at the source code, it's actually mapping over the children of the node. This means that this doesn't work:

```
scala> <b>foo</b>.toSeq.map(_.label)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String] = List(b)

scala> <b>foo</b> \ "b"
res6: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq()
```

and I have to wrap it in a 'dummy' element to make it work. Is this a bug?

Furthermore, using `\\` which bizarrely **doesn't** exclude the current node, and works in the above case. Isn't the behaviour of `\\` and `\` inconsistent?

Comment: Yeah, I believe `\ ` is children, and `\\ ` is descendants or self, since it's trying to simulate XPath where `\\ ` is global.

Comment: ticket https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/issues/178

Comment: what really sucks about this is that you can't use `\ ` to navigate a nested xpath e.g. `x \ "body" \ "navigation"  \ "leftpane"`, which has the advantage over a `match case` pattern that it ignores whitespace ...